# Stylelint not respecting negative-lookahead in ignoreProperties

Tags: stylelint

We're using `stylelint`, and want a rule that forbids using `px` as a unit with `font-size`; but allows it for any other property. We thought this should work:

```
     "unit-disallowed-list": ["px", {
        "ignoreProperties": { "px": ["/^((?!font-size).)*$/"] },
    }],
```

but it catches `px` in other properties as well, for example in `@media (min-width: 380px)`, throwing

```
✖  Unexpected unit "px"   unit-disallowed-list
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

Alternatively, it would be great if we could just specify which properties we want the rule to apply *for*, rather than all those we wish to ignore, but I don't see a way to do this with `stylelint`.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively, it would be great if we could just specify which properties we want the rule to apply for, rather than all those we wish to ignore, but I don't see a way to do this with stylelint.

You can use the [`declaration-property-unit-disallowed-list` rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/declaration-property-unit-disallowed-list/) to do this:

```json
{ 
  "rules": {
    "declaration-property-unit-disallowed-list": {
      "font-size": ["px"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the `unit-disallowed-list` and `declaration-property-unit-disallowed-list` rules together, using the former to disallow units *generally* in your styles and the latter when you want to be more specific.

You may also find it more useful to use the allowed-list, rather than disallowed-list, rules especially when being specific, e.g.:

```json
{ 
  "rules": {
    "declaration-property-unit-allowed-list": {
      "font-size": ["em", "rem"]
    }
  }
}
```